# Could I use std::any with C++17 for pointer to member variable?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++17

I'm studying with std::any
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any.
I'm wondering if I can use it for accessing data members or functino member of class.
I have a struct:

```
struct test
{
    int a;
    double b;
}
```

Then I want a general type that can either test::a or test::b.

```
 std::any ptr;
 ptr = &test::a;
```

Now `ptr` is a pointer to a member `a` of class `test`. And if I create a new object of class `test`. I don't know to set a new value of member `a` of this object. I tried something like following but it is fail at compiler.

```
 test t;
 std::any ptr;
 ptr = &test::a;

 // set a value for member a of object t using ptr ??
 t.*(std::any_cast<test::*>(ptr)) = 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `&test::a` is `int test::*`, so you're just missing the `int` portion:

```
t.*(std::any_cast<int test::*>(ptr)) = 1;
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Yt8vM6nWsOJeeNKG)